# Double square in CSS

Tags: html, css, percentage

I try to create **19** squares, the first double size.

Regular square: `width: 9.09%; padding: 2.27% 0;`. So, I used for the first `width: 18.18%; padding: 4.54% 0;`. But doesn't have double height than the others.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ooLzq85o/).

Which would be the right percentage for `padding`? And why is not *4.54*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no padding in percent that will make the larger square twice as high as the regular squares.

A regular square is one character block high, plus 4.54% of the parent element width. For the larger square to be twice as high, it needs to be two character blocks high, plus 9.08% of the parent element width.

If you put two lines in the block, and set the padding to `4.54% 0`, the larger block will always be twice as high as the regular blocks:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ooLzq85o/3/

If you don't want two character lines in the larger block, then you need to set the line height of the regular blocks, so that you can use double that in the larger block:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ooLzq85o/4/

Answer (score 1):

your forgot to mind the line-height used by your text.

You may reset it to 0: http://jsfiddle.net/ooLzq85o/1/

```css
.button {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    width: 9.09%;
 padding: 4.5% 0;
    background: maroon;
    line-height:0;
}
.double {
    width: 18.18%;
 padding: 9% 0;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
    <div class="button double">1</div>
    <div class="button">2</div>
    <div class="button">3</div>
    <div class="button">4</div>
    <div class="button">5</div>
    <div class="button">6</div>
    <div class="button">7</div>
    <div class="button">8</div>
    <div class="button">9</div>
    <div class="button">10</div>
    <div class="button">11</div>
    <div class="button">12</div>
    <div class="button">13</div>
    <div class="button">14</div>
    <div class="button">15</div>
    <div class="button">16</div>
    <div class="button">17</div>
    <div class="button">18</div>
    <div class="button">19</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use viewport units instead.

```
.button {
    width: 9.09vw;
    height: 9.09vw;
}
.double {
    width: 18.18w;
    height: 18.18vw;
    background: red;
}
```

```css
.buttons {overflow: hidden; }
.button {
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top;
 float: left;
 width: 9.09vw;
    height: 9.09vw;
 background: maroon;
}
.double {
 width: 18.18w;
 height: 18.18vw;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
   <div id="buttons">
    <div class="button double">
     1
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     2
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     3
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     4
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     5
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     6
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     7
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     8
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     9
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     10
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     11
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     12
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     13
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     14
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     15
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     16
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     17
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     18
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     19
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because doubling the padding only doubles the padding. Box model says: visual height = height-content + height-padding + height-border

I recommend you to user border-box as box-sizing model and explicitly set the height of your buttons:
e.g.:

```
.buttons { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /*Cross-Browser-prefixes */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.button {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    background: maroon;
}
.double {
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/usj9u2je/1/